# Python SQLite3 no such table

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sqlite3

При попытке обратиться к таблице в базе данных выдает ошибку 'no such table: users'. Но проблема в том что такая таблица существует и буквально вчера все работало как надо. Обращение к таблице происходит вот так:

```
with sqlite3.connect("data.db") as db:
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM users;")
```

Кто знает в чем может быть проблема и как ее решить?

Comment: а попробуйте любым просмотрщиком базы посмотреть внутрь, может там и нет таблицы?

Comment: @KoVadim есть, смотрю прямо сейчас. И данные со вчерашнего дня на месте

Comment: Может из другой директории запускаете? А там другой файл "data.db" лежит.

Comment: @GrAnd нет, в терминале путь к файлу вручную прописываю, бд лежит рядом с файлом

Comment: путь абсолютный или относительный (пропишите абсолютный для теста)? И запускаете ручками или с IDE (некоторые IDE меняют working directory/рабочий каталог и относительные пути работают некорректно)?

Comment: connect("data.db") ищет файл в рабочей папке. Рабочая папка - та, в которой открыт терминал (если не выполнена команда по смене рабочего каталога из терминала или из скрипта). "в терминале путь к файлу вручную прописываю" не меняет рабочей папки. Поэтому sqlite3 создает пустую бд в рабочей папке, где нет никакой таблицы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как уже написал [@vitidev в комментариях](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1378752/python-sqlite3-no-such-table/1378820#comment2449982_1378752) - скорее всего рабочая директория скрипта не та, которую вы ожидаете. SQLite в этом случае создаст новый пустой файл. Для того, чтобы избежать подобных проблем указывайте **полный путь** к файлу.

Для того чтобы понять в какой директории вы пытаетесь открыть файл - можно сделать так:

```
from pathlib import Path

db_fn = Path("data.db")

if not (db_fn.exists() and db_fn.stat().st_size > 0):
    raise FileNotFoundError(f"file [{db_fn.resolve()}] is empty or doesn't exist!")
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM users")
```

вывод на экран:

```
FileNotFoundError: file [/Users/MaxU/Downloads/data.db] is empty or doesn't exist!
```